# Accessing the ActionExecutingContext using a helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have been struggling with this for the past few hours. All I'm trying to do is pick action parameters  from the current route like this. This method resides inside a simple static helper class.

```
    public static string GetStateName(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var stateParam = filterContext.ActionParameters.Where(p => p.Key == RouteConst.StateName).FirstOrDefault();
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stateParam.Key) ? stateParam.Value.ToType<string>() : string.Empty;
    }
```

However, I do not like the idea of passing in the context every time I have to call this method. Is there a way to access the current executing context just like HttpContext.Current?

**Update**: Using Necros' suggestion, this is what I ended up doing.

public static class ActionExtensions
    {

```
    public static string GetMarketName(this ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {return GetActionParamValue(filterContext, RouteConst.MarketName).ToType<string>();}

    public static string GetStateName(this ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {return GetActionParamValue(filterContext, RouteConst.StateName).ToType<string>();}

    private static string GetActionParamValue(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, string actionParamName)
    {
        var actionParam = filterContext.ActionParameters.Where(p => p.Key == actionParamName).FirstOrDefault();
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionParam.Key) ? actionParam.Value.ToType<string>() : string.Empty;
    }
```

ToType() is another extension method which internally uses Convert.ChangeType(value, type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simply because `ActionExecutingContext` is only valid during `OnActionExecuting` event (or whatever it's called where it originates from). All you can do is make it look nice by making it an extension method.

```
public static string GetStateName(this ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var stateParam = filterContext.ActionParameters.Where(p => p.Key == RouteConst.StateName).FirstOrDefault();
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stateParam.Key) ? stateParam.Value.ToType<string>() : string.Empty;
}
```

and call it like this

```
var stateName = filterContext.GetStateName();
```